# Determine with jQuery which button that was sent based on their order

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, radio-button

**Problem:**

Determine which radio button was sent based on their order and submit the value with PHP.

**HTML table 1 code:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered neutralize" id="itembuttons">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="6"></th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="7"></th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="8"></th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="9"></th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="10"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**HTML table 2 code:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered neutralize" id="itembuttons">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="11"></th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="12"></th>
            <th><input type="radio" name="3" id="3" value="13"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Scenario:**

The above code will generate a POST variable in PHP called "3" that will have a value between 6 and 10 in Table 1 or 11 and 13 in Table 2. However, I would like jQuery to determine which button was actually chosen. So for instance, if I choose 3rd button (value=8 or value=13)) then the value 3 should be sent in a hidden input field. If the 5th button was chosen (value=10) then the value 5 should be sent in a hidden input field.

Comment: Hey, this HTML is invalid, id should always be unique, cheers!

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I will change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/Xa42c/

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function(e) {
    $("input[type=hidden]").val( $(this).val() );

    alert( "Hidden field value is set to " + $(this).val() );
});​
```

Note that you don't need the `id`-s. But if you want to use them they **must** be unique

**UPDATE** To get position use `index()` - http://jsfiddle.net/Xa42c/2/

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", function(e) {
    var index = $("input[type=radio]").index(this) + 1;
    $("input[type=hidden]").val( index );

    alert( "Hidden field value is set to " + index );
});​
```

Comment: Thank you, but now the code is giving me the value of the actual radio button. If the 1st radio button is selected then it should give me the value 1, the 2nd radio button should generate the value 2, and so on (independent of what the value of the radio buttons are).

Comment: Updated to get the position instead of the value

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the ids not being unique.  Try changing them.  If you need some common name you can use the name attribute for the tables.

Answer (score 0):

**Final solution:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]', $('#itembuttons')).click(
        function() {
            var pos = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
            $('#hdnQuestion').val(pos);
            alert( 'The ' + $('#hdnQuestion').attr('name') + ' value is now ' + $('#hdnQuestion').val() );
        }
    );
});
```